# Check the column contains string or not in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have comma-separated string like `675,899,343,294,988`.

My table has values like,

```
ID Values
1  56,78,485
2  90,343,398
3  756,46774,45,4
4  536,394,988
```

Here i want result like : ID 2,values 343 and ID 4,values 988

Comment: How do we know that we should grab the 2nd list element for ID 2, but the third for ID 4?

Comment: do you want a random result ....? ;)

Comment: yeah.,can u give me a sample?

Comment: What happens when two `values` matched in same `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can split values to each row for each Id.

```
 ;WITH CTE AS
(
    --  Convert CSV to rows
    SELECT ID,LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'VALUES' 
    FROM  
    (
         -- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
         SELECT ID,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Values], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
         FROM YourTable    
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE (ID=2 AND [VALUES]='343') OR (ID=4 AND [VALUES]='988')
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to get matching Id, you can do the below

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM
( 
    SELECT 1 ID,  '56,78,485' [Values]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,  '90,343,398'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,  '756,46774,45,4'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,  '536,394,988'
)TAB
```

**QUERY**

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(100)='675,899,343,294,988'

;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'String' 
    FROM  
    (
         -- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
         SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@STR, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data               
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
) 
,CTE2 AS
(
    --  Convert CSV to rows
    SELECT ID,LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'Values' 
    FROM  
    (
         -- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
         SELECT ID,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Values], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
         FROM #TEMP     
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT C2.*
FROM CTE1 c1
JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.String=C2.[VALUES]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `Values` IN(string)
```

Comment: Backticks are for MySQL, not SQL Server.